# Rewriting wildcard domain with HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https

Is it possible to rewrite HTTPS wildcard Domains in nginx or should we create multiple structure /file for each domain?

Lets say i have follwing:

```
1. subdomain1.domain.com
2. subdomain2.domain.com
```

If i do not have HTTPS i used the following which works great:

```
server {
 listen 443;
server_name *.domain.com;
charset utf-8;
}
```

No if i use HTTPS, i would have to write a new block like the following ( using letsencryt)

The following is just a test domain (only 1 domain )

```
 server {
    server_name test.me;
    rewrite ^ https://test.me$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name test.me;
    charset utf-8;
    ...
 }
```

Is it possible to do the same for multiple domains?
     server {
        server_name *.domain.com;
        rewrite ^ https://*.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name *.domain.com;
    charset utf-8;
    ...
 }
```

I tried the above config but it doesnot work, it redirects me to

```
https://%2A.domain.com.domain.com/  (just for test)
```

Is it possible to do something like this ? or Should i have different block for every subdomain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the variables provided by `nginx` to extract the host name from the request line. For example `$host` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) for details):

```
server { 
    server_name .domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```